# 32b x86 assembly scanf usage

Tags: c, assembly, segmentation-fault, scanf

So, I am trying to use the `scanf` function in 32bit ATT assembly and keep getting segmentation faults, despite using pretty much the same code as the example shown in `Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective` and the assembly generated from my own simple C input program. I have no idea what it is I am doing wrong and would appreciate some help in figuring it out.

My test assembly code(which segfaults):

```
    .data
    .align  4
fmt:    .string "%d"
str:    .string "Input a number: "
    .text

    .global main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp

    subl    $40, %esp

    movl    $str, (%esp)
    call    printf

    leal    36(%esp), %eax
    movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
    movl    $fmt, (%esp)
    call    scanf

    pushl   -4(%ebp)
    call    printf

    movl    %ebp, %esp
    popl    %ebp
    ret
```

The C code and it's assembly:

C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    printf("%s\n","Enter 2 numbers:");
    scanf("%d %d",&i,&j);
    printf("i = %d and j = %d\n",i,j);
    return 0;
}
```

assembly:

```
    .file   "scan.c"
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "Enter 2 numbers:"
.LC1:
    .string "%d %d"
.LC2:
    .string "i = %d and j = %d\n"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    andl    $-16, %esp
    subl    $32, %esp
    movl    $.LC0, (%esp)
    call    puts
    leal    28(%esp), %eax
    movl    %eax, 8(%esp)
    leal    24(%esp), %eax
    movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
    movl    $.LC1, (%esp)
    call    __isoc99_scanf
    movl    28(%esp), %edx
    movl    24(%esp), %eax
    movl    %edx, 8(%esp)
    movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
    movl    $.LC2, (%esp)
    call    printf
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

The example in the book(in a cropped screenshot): [image: http://i.imgur.com/zYaHZP5.jpg]

Comment: What platform is this for?

Comment: @DavidHoelzer `$fmt` is the value of the symbol `fmt`, `fmt` is the value at address `$fmt`. You got it the wrong way round.

Comment: Unless the compiler is doing it wrong, I do indeed want `$fmt`.

Comment: @FUZxxl If I got your question right, it's for unix.

Comment: @Sunspawn Different Unices have different calling conventions and symbol naming schemes. It would help if you could narrow it down to one system.

Comment: @FUZxxl Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Comment removed.  See, this is why I hate AT&T notation. :)

Comment: @DavidHoelzer Please do not remove your comments. They give valuable insight into what others think about the problem and are helpful for future readers.

Comment: @FUZxxl They're not useful to future readers when they're completely wrong. ;)

Comment: @DavidHoelzer My correction is useful but it only makes sense if your error is seen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply forgot the format string for the `printf`.
You effectively do `printf(i)` instead of `printf("%d", i)`.
Thus change:

```
pushl   -4(%ebp)
call    printf
```

To:

```
pushl   -4(%ebp)
pushl   $fmt
call    printf
```

PS: learn to use a debugger.

Comment: I was about to write this.

Comment: Since I can push strings from the data segment in this way without a format string, I thought I could do it with just random numbers. Apparently not.

Comment: When you pass a string that **is** the format string. You can do `printf("hello");` which has `hello` as a format string without any specifiers. Note that the prototype (as any C reference will tell you) is: `int printf(const char *format, ...);`